# "No route matches" after installing HyperLoop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, react.rb

I'm getting an error when I start rails in development

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"index", :client_id=>"bd881667-ee11-441e-a98f-6f6a6005435a-53d08ea16f47a449a12861c8ebf6e1d3", :controller=>"reception"}
```

It seems to be coming from a link:
`reception_index_url`

rake routes shows

```
reception_index GET    /reception(.:format)      reception#index
```

so the route is there but I'm guessing :client_id is the problem. I have added `mount HyperMesh::Engine => '/rr'` to routes.rb

What am I missing?

Comment: How does your client route class look like?

Comment: I don't have a client model/controller so no client route

Comment: I think client_id is coming from synchromesh_controller.rb in hypermesh

Comment: Problem seems to have gone away after rebooting my computer